Unable to build a github package that reference a package already published in github
We have two repositories each one contains an angular library

lib_a
lib_b  (that uses the package lib_a)

lib_a is built and published in git-hub packages (ver 0.0.4)
The issue is on building lib_b (here is the output of workflow action):
build.yml is the following
name: "Build package"
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on:
      - ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4.0.3
        with:
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          scope: '@app'
      - name: Build
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build
          cd dist/lib_b && npm publish
 

Run npm install
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm error code E403
npm error 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@app/lib_a/0.0.4/82727a643d29921f0d18d3ba84e7aef5fb9daea9 - Permission permission_denied: read_package
npm error 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm error 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm error 403 on a server you do not have access to.

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-08-27T07_36_05_595Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


In the root of your project (package.json) location, create an .npmrc file. In that set the proper authentication registry and it should work.
@username:registry = https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken={{token}}

This applies for private packages install in local machine.

For github actions, you can try specifying the npm token, which you can configure using this guide
steps:
  - run: |
      npm install
  - env:
      NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}


when I tried to create the token on npm token create --scope=@app --auth-type=legacy --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com   I got  "Not Found - POST https://npm.pkg.github.com/-/npm/v1/tokens"
